# Como arrumar os limites do eixo x no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
k <- c(294131, 734127, 817963)
ano <- c(1991, 2000, 2010)
dados <- data.frame(k, ano)
```

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
ggplot(dados,aes(x=ano,y=k)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1991, 2010))
```

Porem o gráfico fica assim:[image]

Queria que não aparecesse os anos 2005 e 1995, mas sim 1991.

Answer (score 2):

Ou se for possível tomar os valores de x como discretos à partida:

```
g <- ggplot(dados, aes(x=factor(ano), y = k, group = 1))
g + geom_point() +
 geom_line() +
 labs(list(x='ano', y='k'))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Andrei,

o parâmetro `limits` serve para definir os limites e não os pontos. Para o que queres deves utilizar o parâmetro `breaks`

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = ano, y = k)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1991, 2000, 2010))
```